# Python average Interval and exponential distribution

Tags: python, distribution, exponential

Im working on an assignment that required me to calculate arrivals that come in an average of a 15 minute interval and follow an exponential distribution. I havent worked with Python a ton and dont know if im doing it right. This is my code:

```
[random.expovariate(.15) for i in range(50)]
```

Any insight will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
intervals = [random.expovariate(1./15) for i in range(50)]
```

will generate 50 time intervals (in minutes) between arrivals, that will average in 15 minutes. I. e., first arrival will occur at `interval[0]`, second one at `interval[0] + interval[1]`, and so on. Note, that it's **`1./15`**, not **`.15`**.

If by "calculate arrivals" you mean to get the binary array of 50 elements with 1's corresponding to arrivals, then you should have a look at a Poisson process, since [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) describes the time between events in a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process).

Comment: perfect! Thank you!